# Ошибки подключения при простое бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

При простое бота со временем начинает спамить в терминал ошибками. Не получается найти инфрмацию на сколько это проблема и как пофиксить. Самое странное, что не смотря на все эти варнинги и ерроры если обратиться к боту он спокойно отвечает как буд то ошибок и небыло.

```
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher:Failed to fetch updates - TelegramNetworkError: ServerDisconnectedError: Server disconnected 
WARNING:aiogram.dispatcher:Sleep for 1.000000 seconds and try again... (tryings = 0, bot id = *111111111*)
```

Запуск бота вот такой

```
async def starter():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO
    )

    await dp.start_polling(bots)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(starter())
```

Айограмм используется 3.х

Comment: Сначала тоже подумал о проблемах с сетью, но на запросы то бот реагирует при этом и ошибка пропадает. Она именно при простое возникает как будто. А третий потому что начал только изучение процесса написания бота и даже если он сырой, когда т его допилят и я посчитал что не рационально изучать что то что может через время утратить актуальность. Не хотелось бы вдруг резко переделывать бота более чем на тыс строк просто из-за обновления версии

Comment: Как решили проблему? Столкнулся с этой же бедой. Бот зависает и все пользователи ждут ровно 1 минуту ответа. Попробую тоже получить текст ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

данное поведение явно прописано в тексте aiogram - достаточно поискать текст ошибки

```
try:
    updates = await bot(get_updates, **kwargs)
except Exception as e:
    failed = True
    # In cases when Telegram Bot API was inaccessible don't need to stop polling
    # process because some developers can't make auto-restarting of the script
    loggers.dispatcher.error("Failed to fetch updates - %s: %s", type(e).__name__, e)
```